# newer php version and loading lang files issue

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm using tinymce html editor with imagemanager and filemanager plugin together with php. Everything works fine on server where is php verstion 5.2.17 is installed.

On server where is PHP version  5.4.21 installed i have problem with displaying imagemanager window, on popup window (imagemanager) I'm getting this

{#common.filter}
{#common.directory}

instead of corresponding langauge strings.

[image]

Comment: Did you check your error.log?

Comment: no error.log exist, double checked.